# How to get pip to use correct version of cython in building requirements for Heroku push

Tags: python, ubuntu, heroku

OS: Biolinux 8 based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I am not experienced, this is my first post, just learning to develop front end web apps. (Basic N00B)

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku for the first time. 
The test app provided in the tutorial ran smoothly both on web and local.

In the process of setting up my app with **Flask**, I ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt` that was out put to my repo's root folder.

**Procfile and web app files already generated**

The resulting file had this entry on line 1;

> Cython==0.20.1.post0

When I ran `git push heroku master`, I got the following output;

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.  
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.2
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting Cython==0.20.1.post0 (from -r /tmp/build_63aace3295cb1453f6de1395392f3225/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:        Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython==0.20.1.post0 
               (from -r /tmp/build_63aace3295cb1453f6de1395392f3225/requirements.txt (line 1)) 
               (from versions: 0.9.6.5, 0.9.6.6, 0.9.6.7, 0.9.6.8, 0.9.6.10b0, 0.9.6.10, 0.9.6.10.1, 0.9.6.11b0, 0.9.6.11, 
               0.9.6.12, 0.9.6.13, 0.9.6.13.1, 0.9.6.14, 0.9.8, 
               0.9.8.1, 0.9.8.1.1, 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.11, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13,
               0.14, 0.14.1, 0.15, 0.15.1, 0.16, 0.17, 0.17.1, 0.17.2, 0.17.3, 0.17.4, 0.18, 0.19, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 
               0.20, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.21, 0.21.1, 0.21.2, 0.22, 0.22.1, 
               0.23, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.23.5, 0.24, 0.24.1, 0.25, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.26, 0.26.1, 0.27)
remote:        No matching distribution found for Cython==0.20.1.post0 (from -r /tmp/build_63aace3295cb1453f6de1395392f3225/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to limitless-wave-64303.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/limitless-wave-64303.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/limitless-wave-64303.git'
```

I edited out the offending Cython version from the `requirements.txt` file 
but apparently that's not the file causing problems anymore.

I have tried to reboot in the hopes that it would clear the /tmp folder where the new `requirements.txt` file is being generated without luck.

I have upgraded Cython to version 0.24 but when I try to push, pip still searches Cython version 0.20.1.post0

**How do I get pip to fix it's requirements file and use a valid version of Cython or not at all?? It seems Cython isn't even necessary for the deployment**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pip, try using pip3. So in your example, you would run 
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt. Or you can alias pip with pip3. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the fix.

Running `heroku create` on a repo containing a requirements.txt file that has unknown versions of dependencies will corrupt it.

So having fixed the requirements file, 
I needed to run `heroku create` again so that it would build a remote that loads up the "clean" requirements file.

Thanks for the help!